# Exclude columns by names in mutate_at in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to do something very simple, and yet can't figure out the right way to specify. I simply want to exclude some named columns from `mutate_at`. It works fine if I specify position, but I don't want to hard code positions.

For example, I want the same output as this:

```
mtcars %>% mutate_at(-c(1, 2), max)
```

But, by specifying `mpg` and `cyl` column names.

I tried many things, including:

```
mtcars %>% mutate_at(-c('mpg', 'cyl'), max)
```

Is there a way to work with names and exclusion in `mutate_at`?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You can use `vars` to specify the columns, which works the same way as `select()` and allows you to exclude columns using `-`:

```
mtcars %>% mutate_at(vars(-mpg, -cyl), max)
```

Answer (score 11):

One option is to pass the strings inside `one_of`

```
mtcars %>% 
     mutate_at(vars(-one_of("mpg", "cyl")), max)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since this question was asked, `mutate_at()` (along with `mutate_if()`, and `mutate_all()`) have been superseded by using [pick](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/pick.html) and [across](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/across.html).

Conveniently, the example OP gave works perfectly using across, with no further modifications needed!

```
mtcars |> mutate(across(-c("mpg", "cyl"), max))
```